# React app detect if user refresh window or navigated away

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to be able to detect if the user refreshed the window or navigated away (say google.com) and then return to the page so I can trigger an event.

I tried different onbeforeunload but it wasnt detecting it.

I tried, this and it wasnt working or triggering the console.log.

```
componentDidUpdate()
{
      window.addEventListener("onbeforeunload",function (){
        console.log('Page Refreshed')
     })
      
}
```

However, that doesnt even trigger the console.log message.  I have also tried beforeunload and same results

any ideas why?

Comment: `onbeforeunload` ---> `beforeunload`

Comment: @Yousaf I tried that and it didnt trigger it.

Comment: In that case, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can test the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to detect a page reload is to use `window.performance.navigation` which returns an object for the page containing two key-value pairs `{ redirectCount: 0 , type: 0 }` shown below:

```js
console.log(window.performance.navigation)
```

When the key `type` is equal to a value which is non-zero for example - `type: 1` it depicts a page reload.

**Note:** Most probably the snippet won't work as expected. In that case you can switch to browser console and check it out yourself and don't forget to `check` the `Preserve log` checkbox under `network tab` of browser console.

To check if page is navigating away. Try `unload` event instead of `onbeforeunload`.

```js
window.addEventListener("unload", function (e) {
  console.log('going away', e)
})
```

Lastly, in case of page load you can use lifecycle hooks. You can run some code as soon as the page loads in `useEffect()` of react-hooks in react or `componentDidMount()` if you're using class based syntax.

1. `useEffect()`

   ```
    useEffect(() => {
     // Run as soon as page loads
     console.log('page loaded');
    });
   ```
2. `componentDidMount()`

   ```
    componentDidMount() {
     // Run as soon as page loads
     console.log('page loaded'); 
    }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
  console.log('Page Refreshed');
};
```

If you don't see the console you have to preserve the logs in the console.

Comment: How would I trigger and action after the page loads?

Comment: Thats a separate thing. Now if you want to do something when a page loads you can use ```componentDidMount()``` . If you want to store some value before refresh and use that value after refresh you have to use browser storage ```sessionStorage``` or ```cookie```

Answer (score 1):

The event name is not recognized, in addEventListener the event name should be "beforeunload".
"onbeforeonload" is window property, use it like "window.onbeforeunload = funcName".

If your console log didnt show, it might be cleared by browser, try persist the log, then see it console.log shows up